# Can't copy orgs with Migration Tool

Tags: ant, migration, deployment, ci

I'm trying to implement CI for the company I work for, and having troubles with the Migration Tool. I got a package.xml with all the metadata information from my origin org, and I'm trying to deploy it to a new, completely clean org. However, I'm getting a lot of errors (like 667 errors!) while deploying to the clean org. Some of them include:

```
[sf:deploy] 19.  objects/Trabalho__c.object (Trabalho__c.SBF_Contecnica1_Trabalho) -- Error: This View Unique Name already exists or has been previously used.  Please choose a different name. (line 1027, column 16)
[sf:deploy] 72.  reports/Financeiro_Plenos_ADM/Emprestimos.report -- Error: filterlanguage: Invalid value specified: 64.
[sf:deploy] 115.  reports/Plenos_ADM_e_ENG/Encargos_Sociais.report -- Error: filterlanguage: Invalid value specified: 64.
[sf:deploy] 238.  workflows/Apontamento__c.workflow (Apontamento__c.SE_Envio_do_email_do_RDA) -- Error: In field: recipient - no User named name@company found (line 48, column 13)
[sf:deploy] 336.  classes/Teste_Trabalho_AtualizaSugestaoCrea.cls -- Error: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
    build   28-Apr-2015 16:44:16
[sf:deploy]       Teste_Cria_Objetos: line 7, column 55: Invalid field cnpj__c for SObject Account (line 5, column 5)
[sf:deploy] 414.  profiles/SolutionManager.profile -- Warning: You can't edit tab settings for SocialPersona, as it's not a valid tab.
[sf:deploy] 443.  email/unfiled$public/Informacoes_do_Diario_clonado.email -- Error: Apex class 'doDisplayController' does not exist
```

What I find odd about this is that some errors, like the 443 (the last one above), tell that a class does not exist, while the same class is specified in the package.xml in the retrieve and deploy methods.

Has anyone ever experienced something like this before? What can I do to successfully copy a whole Salesforce org?

PS:

I have access to the sandbox, and other clean orgs. I don't have access to the original org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a cloned org from scratch is at best painful. You need to read each message in the order they appear to determine the root cause. The error 443? It's caused by the controller falling to compile, and was thus not created. This might be because of the unique list view error, or another reason. It's very likely that any error in a significantly large deployment will generate hundreds or thousands of errors. You need to start from error #1, fix it, and try again. Repeat until no errors remain.